# Swift - Difference limit for closed range slider

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, range

I am trying to make a slider where the overall range should be 0-300. But I am putting a range on the slider so a user can choose between 0-10 or 20-30 for example. The problem I am facing is figuring out how to make the range stay within 10 units of eachother.
The following line is what where I declared the position/range:

```
@State var sliderPosition: ClosedRange<Float> = 0...10
```

Comment: Do you mean "allowed sub-range" so of entire slider's range a user could slide only within, e.g. 20...30?

Comment: _"...stay within 10 units of eachother"_, I assume this means that the range can somehow change, ie move between 0-300 but always be of size 10?

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach is to intercept bound value by proxy computable binding and do all validations inside.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Here is main part:

```
@State private var allowed: ClosedRange<Double> = 10...20

var proxy: Binding<Double> {
    Binding(
        get: { value },
        set: {
            value = allowed.contains($0) ? $0 : value
        }
    )
}
```

[Test code on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestLimitSliderToSubrange.swift)